# Why does Amelia refer to Cinderella in final scenes to casper?

Tags: plot-explanation, casper

In  **Casper**, Why does **Amelia** refer to **Cinderella** and the princess's age in the final scenes while talking to Casper?

> Cinderella wasn't 12 years old.

**I don't understand why she mentioned Cinderella here.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It is a reference to Casper getting what he desires, but only for a set time, just like the story of Cinderella.

In the story, [Cinderella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinderella) got her wish to go to the ball, with the understanding that it would last until midnight - when the spell would be broken.

Casper is evidently familiar with the story, so when Amelia says he's getting the 'Cinderella deal', he thinks it'll last until midnight.

Due to his young age, Amelia apparently doesn't want Casper to stay up until midnight.

> Amelia: You fulfilled his greatest dream, Casper, and I know he is very, very proud of you. And for what you've done, I'm giving you your dream in return.But it's just for tonight. Sort of a Cinderella deal.
>
> Casper: So I have until midnight?
>
> Amelia: 10:00.
>
> Casper: Hey, Cinderella got until midnight.
>
> Amelia: Cinderella wasn't 12 years old.

Answer (score -2):

It is just a figure of speech.She was talking to **Casper** like that as a way of saying how old Casper was when he died of the cold he mentioned and as a comparison. She probably just said it because maybe she watched cinderella a lot and other princess movies when she was younger? It is just a figure of speech.